# River drawing tips?

Tags: modeling

I am learning the use of Blender by following tutorials online.
My goal is to draw a 3D model of an underground river in a cave for my research. I have informations of depth at various locations.
Here is the map of the cave with the river in "gray". I imported the map and scaled it. Now I want to delineate the river banks based on the map. Then I'll add the depth.
Have you any tips on the way(s) to draw the shapes of the river ? Is there a tool ideal for this, a tutorial specifically for this ?
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would start with a plane and work with it until the shape is right in 2D.

Start at one end - I'd go for the thicker end to the left of the Dome text - at the very edge and subdivide/extrude the edges until it's the shape of the area, leaving a nice flat edge where the river stretches on for me to grab and extrude when I'm ready to draw out that area.

Once I've got the whole thing mapped in 2D, I'd go in and subdivide as required, then pull my geometry down slightly where I know my depths. There's a proportional editing tool that creates a falloff effect on nearby geometry when you move a point. By default you can enable it in Edit mode by pressing the O key. I'd use this to begin with, and drag a string of edges along the centre of the river downwards to give me a nice U-shaped profile to start with, but you have a better idea of the shape and depth of your river than I do :)

Off the top of my head, I don't know of a tutorial specifically for this, nor a tool that would automate much of it. It's just a case of modelling and tweaking until you've got the shapes right.